# MapView/Annotation: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, annotations, maps, mapkit, mkannotation

I have the following function that is supposed to drop a pin onto a map at the user's current location. This is from a note detail view controller, dropping it onto a map that's in another tab.

```
    @IBAction func dropPin(sender: UIButton) {

    //creates instance of map from MapController class
    let map = MapController().mapView
    let point:MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

   //converts CGPoint to CLLOcationCoordinate2D
    let coord:CLLocationCoordinate2D = map.convertPoint(map.center, toCoordinateFromView: map)

       //assigns map coord to annotation coordinate
        point.coordinate = coord
        point.title = note.title

        //adds annotation to map
        map.addAnnotation(point)

        }

    }
```

I'm getting the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error. I know it's because map is returning nil, and I presume it's because I'm not initializing my map before I'm dropping a pin in it– but I don't know how to fix it. It may also be another reason. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Presumably `MapController()` is a UIViewController subclass that you have created?  The problem you have is that you have just instantiated a new instance of this ViewController, so it won't have any of the controls initialised.  You need to get a reference to the existing view controller somehow but you haven't provided enough code - What class is this method in?

Comment: this method is in a UIViewController, my DetailView. I have it setup like this:

1. [TableView of notes] -> [DetailView of a specific note].
In the DetailView, there is a small button that is supposed to produce the annotation.

Comment: and yes, MapController() a subclass.

Comment: Which view controller has the map?  The detail view controller?  If so then you just use `let map=self.mapView`

Comment: no, the MapController view controller has the map. imagine this is a two tabbed application: 1 tab with a tableview, and 1 with a map. every time a note is created in the table view, theres a button inside of the note detail view that is supposed to create the annotation

Comment: Ok, then you are going to have to keep a reference to the map view controller somehow - possibly through the tab view controller

Comment: @Paulw11 , I just uploaded a new question that contains the file to my project. Please check it out if you can, I still haven't figured out the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925497/debug-with-mapkit-troubles